# Select the service you wish to carry out a Google Task Handler

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

I am relatively new to Google Cloud Platform, and I am able to create app services, and manage databases. I am attempting to create a handler within Google Cloud Tasks (similar to the NodeJS sample found in [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-appengine-handlers?authuser=2).

However, the documentation fails to clearly address how to connect the deployed service with what is requesting. Necessity requires that I have more than one service in my project (one in Node for managing rest, and another in Python for managing geospatial data as asynchronous tasks).

My question: When running multiple services, how does Google Cloud Tasks know which service to direct the task towards?

Screenshot below as proof that I am able to request tasks to a queue.

[image: Sample tasks running in queue]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using App Engine routing for your tasks it will route it to the "default" service. However, you can overwrite this by defining [`AppEngineRouting`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/tasks/latest/google.cloud.tasks.v2.html#.AppEngineRouting), select your service, instance and version, the [`AppEngineHttpRequest`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/tasks/latest/google.cloud.tasks.v2.html#.AppEngineHttpRequest) field.

The [sample](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-appengine-tasks) shows a task routed to the default service's `/log_payload` endpoint.

```
const task = {
  appEngineHttpRequest: {
    httpMethod: 'POST',
    relativeUri: '/log_payload',
  },
};
```

You can update this to:

```
const task = {
  appEngineHttpRequest: {
    httpMethod: 'POST',
    relativeUri: '/log_payload',
    appEngineRouting: {
      service: 'non-default-service'
    }
  },
};
```

Learn more about [configuring routes](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-queues#routing).

Answer (score 0):

I wonder which "services" you are talking about, because it always is the current service. These HTTP requests are basically being dispatched by HTTP headers `HTTP_X_APPENGINE_QUEUENAME` and `HTTP_X_APPENGINE_TASKNAME`... as you have them in the screenshot with `sample-tasks` and `some random numbers`. If you want to task other services, these will have to have their own task queue(s).