# Cloud Tasks are stuck in queue and are not executed

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-functions, task-queue, google-cloud-tasks

I am using Cloud Functions to put tasks into Cloud Tasks Queue and invoke a service (worker) function. Both the task generator and task Handler functions are deployed to Cloud Functions.
This is my createTask.js:

```
const {CloudTasksClient} = require('@google-cloud/tasks');
const client = new CloudTasksClient();

exports.createTask = async (req, res) =>  {

  const location = 'us-central1';
  const project = 'project-id';
  const queue = 'queueid';
  const payload = 'Hello, World!';
  const parent = client.queuePath(project, location, queue);
const task = { appEngineHttpRequest: {
        
            httpMethod: 'POST',
            relativeUri : '/log_payload'}, 
 const [ response ] = await tasksClient.createTask({ parent: queuePath, task })

  if (payload) {
    task.appEngineHttpRequest.body = Buffer.from(payload).toString('base64');
  }
  let inSeconds = 0 ;
  if (inSeconds) {
    // The time when the task is scheduled to be attempted.
    task.scheduleTime = {
      seconds: inSeconds + Date.now() / 1000,
    };
  }

  console.log('Sending task:');
  console.log(task);
  // Send create task request.
  const request = {parent: parent, task: task};
  const [response] = await client.createTask(request);
  const name = response.name;
  console.log(`Created task ${name}`);
  res.send({message : "Ok"});
}
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.enable('trust proxy');
app.use(bodyParser.raw({type: 'application/octet-stream'}));
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  // Basic index to verify app is serving
  res.send('Hello, World!').end();
});
app.post('/log_payload', (req, res) => {
  // Log the request payload
  console.log('Received task with payload: %s', req.body);
  res.send(`Printed task payload: ${req.body}`).end();
});
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.send('OK').end();
});
app.listen(3000 , () => {
  console.log(`App listening on port`);
  console.log('Press Ctrl+C to quit.');
});
```

When I run trigger the task generator function via HTTP trigger in Postman, the task is added to the queue but it stays there forever.
The queue looks like this:

[image]

The logs of the handler task show it was never triggered. The task in the queue cannot reach its handler.
The logs of task in queue looks like this:

[image]

The task is failed and is in the queue:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RL1zc.png)

Comment: As mentioned in doc[1](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-appengine-tasks) sample can you try changing relativeUri: '/log_payload' .You may have a look at this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58125831/select-the-service-you-wish-to-carry-out-a-google-task-handler)

Comment: I followed the SO thread you shared. But nothing has changed. Regarding the thread, the answer didn't mention where to write the name of the worker function to be invoked.

Comment: Can you check this link[1](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/push/retrying-tasks#retrying_tasks),[2](https://joncloudgeek.com/blog/managing-background-jobs-with-cloud-tasks/) that explains Retrying Failed Push Tasks & also check this [specifying the worker service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/push/creating-tasks)

Comment: Thank you. I am working with Create App Engine tasks in Javascript. And my tasks in queue can't trigger the assigned worker. Above links aren't of any help in my case. I am confused about "relativeUri" parameter that defines routing of request sent to worker. I think it is what is causing the problem.

Comment: The scheduling time has to be configured for the task in a future time when it should be executed. Otherwise the task will only be added to the queue and remain unexecuted.
add this
ScheduleTime = Timestamp.FromDateTime(                 DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(inSeconds))

Comment: It is not a scheduled task. It is triggered through HTTP request. Now what I don't know don't understand is, what would be the value of that URL?

Comment: Have you followed this [document](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.queues.tasks#appenginehttprequest) while configuring? and can you share complete code by editing the question

Comment: @SathiAiswarya I have shared the whole code. Both the createTask and server functions are deployed to Cloud. I am using Postman to trigger createTask and the task gets added to the queue. But it stays there. The handler is not triggered.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried to reproduce the issue by following [doc](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/add-task-queue). Successfully  tasks are executed.I assume you also followed [Cloud Task quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/add-task-queue) & [Github code samples](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-tasks/tree/main/samples) for  set-up. This quickstart attempts to set up following components -

a) Create Task (~ createTask.js) - This can be either run locally or deployed as a Cloud function. In your case, this has been created as a Cloud Function.

b) Task Queue Creation - This is the creation of a Cloud Task queue.

c) Task Target / Handler (~ server.js) - The [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/add-task-queue#set_up_the_sample) assumes this component to be deployed as an App Engine worker instance. This can also be seen in the corresponding [Task Creation script](https://screenshot.googleplex.com/BzEaFyWbK2hQk63) (~ createTask.js).

Based on the description, assuming  you are deploying the Task Target / Handler also as a cloud function If this assumption is correct then you need to follow this public [doc](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks) to create a HTTP Target Task which uses "httpRequest" instead of "appEngineHttpRequest" construct. There is also a [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/tutorial-gcf), that you may find helpful.

If you are using Cloud Functions  instead of App Engine, Target for Tasks  is also supported by the error - "404 - Not Found" in those screenshots you provided. This [error](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/status-codes#404_Not_Found) signifies that the target App Engine instance endpoint (~ log_payload) is not found. This is also the reason why the task is not getting executed.

I suggest you to try out the above steps if those does not help I think  you may raise support case [here](https://cloud.google.com/contact#:%7E:text=Get%20support%20for%20my%20current%20Google%20Cloud%20product(s)) as your  issue seems to require more in-depth analysis in your project logs to see why task queues are not being triggered.